# Generic nested Options pattern matching

Tags: scala, generics, pattern-matching

I have this data structures with case class in an option and the field being wrapped in an option as well:

```
case class Name(value: Option[String]) extends AnyVal
case class Data(id: Int, name: Option[Name], isDefault: Boolean)
```

So I would like to handle cases when there is some for the Name, the same goes for upper Option. But when there is None for the Name I would like to have `None` as the result instead of `Some(Name(None))`.
I tried to do something like this:

```
def handleNestedOptions(value: Option[String]): Option[Name] = {
  value match {
    case Some(data) => Some(Name(Some(data)))
    case None => None
  }
}
```

But I also would like to have it in a generic way so it could work for any case class of the same structure I have. So how can I change this implementation to make it more generic?
By generic I mean something like this:
`def handleNestedOptions[T, K](value: Option[K]): Option[T]`

Comment: @jwvh I've mixed it up, there should be Name instead of Data. I have updated the question with the right one

Comment: What do you mean with `the same goes for upper Option`?

Comment: I mean that if a value of a Name is Some than the Name should be 2 somes: `Some(Name(Some(data)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way about it.

```
def handleNestedOptions[T,U](value :Option[T], f :Option[T]=>U) :Option[U] =
  if (value.isEmpty) None
  else Option(f(value))

handleNestedOptions(None, Name)        //res0: Option[Name] = None
handleNestedOptions(Some("str"), Name) //res1: Option[Name] = Some(Name(Some(str)))
```